# Parameterize block of text using Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following text in Notepad++

```
A
B
C
D
```

I would like to "parameterize" this text and turn it into this using a regex or some other native Notepad++ command(s) or plugin:

```
'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'
```

Note that I want the end text to be on one line and no trailing comma, if possible. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283608/using-regex-to-prefix-and-append-in-notepad) gets me close but I am left with a trailing comma and the text is not compacted to one line. Is there anyway to accomplish this in Notepad++ ***without*** using a macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in Regex Search Mode.

Search for `(\w)\r\n`

Replace with `('\1', )`

But you will have to remove the space and a comma manually from the end of the line.

Comment: The answer from stema satisfied all my requirements (with conditions) but this approach seemed faster to execute overall so I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two steps:

1. Search for e.g. `(\w+)` and replace with `'$1'`

   The `\w+` will find the letters (and digits and the underscore), at least one.
2. Search for `(\s+)` and replace with `,`

   `\s+` will find whitespace characters, that means here the newline characters at the end of a row. If you have whitespace in your text, you want to keep, use `[\r\n]+` instead.

This way, **if there is no newline after the last letter**, there will be no trailing comma.