# How to delete duplicate words from text file by Notepad++

Tags: file, notepad++, text-files, words

For example my text is :

```
090111FB2F00LLDEJ3RA
090111FB2F00LLDEJ3RA:N73402363904
```

I want to delete the first line and keep the second line.

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283608/using-regex-to-prefix-and-append-in-notepad

Answer (score 0):

This is the way:

Find:

```
^(\w+?)$\n^(?=\1\:\w+?)
```

Replace:

```
<leave empty>
```

Don't forget to tick the "Regular expression" checkbox in the Replace dialogue before replacing!

Detailed explanation of the regex: http://regex101.com/r/xQ0cY2