# Convert Dates with Regular Expression 1/1/18 -> 2018-01-01

Tags: regex

I have dates that are in **m/d/yy** but need to convert them to **yyyy-dd-mm** format. I have the following regex
`(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})` with this replace `20$3-$1-$2`. I'm assuming year 2000 which is okay but this breaks for single digit days and months.

Is there any way to prefix the days and months with 0 if the match is on a single digit?

Comment: Are you working this in PHP?

Comment: The expression will be evaluated in the browser via Javascript using the `Regex()` implementation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1):

It might be usefull for you.
Add zero padding to single digit dates:
[Regex to add leading zero in date record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37159034/regex-to-add-leading-zero-in-date-record)

Comment: Thanks. Is this a Notepad++ only implementation? I can't seem to get it to work in https://regex101.com.

Comment: Notepad++ uses Perl/PCRE syntax regexp. You just need to replace different marks in Perl style for JS regex syntax style.
It might be usefull:
https://www.regextester.com/6

In this site: https://regex101.com/ you have few types of syntax pcre(php), javascript, python, golang. Try to test it all :)