# Regex add leading zeros to DD.MM.YYYY string

Tags: javascript, regex

I was sure something like this had been answered before in some manner however I only managed to find reveresed versions like MM/DD/YYYY etc or special characters like / - and had little luck converting them as my regex knowledge is terrible.

The closest thread I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37159034/regex-to-add-leading-zero-in-date-record)

I am struggling to find a clean approach using regex and javascript to add trailing zeros to the below string format?

```
dd.mm.yyyy
```

Eg 1.1.1998 => 01.01.1998 || 10.1.1998 => 10.01.1998

my current approach is along the lines of

```
const addLeadingZeros = (input: string) => {
   return input.replace(/.([1-9])(?!\d)/g, '.0$1');
}
```

Comment: You have to use regex? Using moment.js is out of the question?

Comment: Yeah I believe so, I am concatenating the date values from seperate string values.

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy moment.js is no longer supported.

Comment: @Kordrad so? It's stable and is powerful, it saved my life on more than one occasion :)

Comment: @PengProgrammer If you already have the date parts as separate strings, you can use `("0" + s).slice(-2)` to left-pad each part with a "0" to a final length of 2.

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy that's true but they themself say `Considering using Moment in your project? There may be better modern alternatives.` So if you don't use it in a project yet you should use their suggested alternative.

Comment: @t.niese this isn't a debate we should have in here, it's a personal choice. It depends on the project you're working on.

Comment: @AndrewMorton this could work, however I was specifically looking for a regex based approach :) Thanks!

Comment: If str contains only date, [here another simple regex](https://tio.run/##HctBCoAgEEDRvadwEWRQk7oqIjpIBYkMUUiKStDpzdr@xz/VrYL2h4vN3aVEDEYaoqcj3bgACZJLsQ2E/OAxZMgMHp1RGlnLJzaLpl@rBdr9qUteCCirPGh7BWsQjN1Z/r6U0gs) that might suffice.

Comment: Can't you just replace `\b(?=\d\b)` with `0`? For example like [so](https://regex101.com/r/Ax0aoZ/1)

Comment: @JvdV Yes that will work and I believe is a more elegant solution, dankie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
input.replace(/(?<=^|\.)(\d)(?=\.|$)/g, '0$1');
```

It means: "replace all digits preceded by the beginning of a line or a dot *and* followed by a dot or the end of the line". This example works only for day and month parts.

Example (browser console outputs):

```
"01.01.1998".replace(/(?<=^|\.)(\d)(?=\.|$)/g, '0$1');
← "01.01.1998"
"1.01.1998".replace(/(?<=^|\.)(\d)(?=\.|$)/g, '0$1');
← "01.01.1998"
"1.1.1998".replace(/(?<=^|\.)(\d)(?=\.|$)/g, '0$1');
← "01.01.1998"
```

*(**Note:** this is not a solution I particularly recommend, I just focused on the asked point.)*

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```js
const addLeadingZeros = (input: string) => {
   return input.replaceAll(/\d*(?<![\d])[\d](?=[.])/g, '0$&');
}
```

The regex: `\d*(?<![\d])[\d](?=[.])`

You can find the explanation about it [here](https://regex101.com/r/XczTt3/1).

[image: explanation]

```js
const addLeadingZeros = (input) => {
   return input.replaceAll(/\d*(?<![\d])[\d](?=[.])/g, '0$&');
}

console.log(addLeadingZeros('01.02.3456'))
console.log(addLeadingZeros('1.2.2001'))
console.log(addLeadingZeros('01.2.1234'))
console.log(addLeadingZeros('1.12.1998'))
console.log(addLeadingZeros('3.04.2021'))
console.log(addLeadingZeros('5.6.01'))
console.log(addLeadingZeros('5.06.01'))
console.log(addLeadingZeros('05.6.01'))
console.log(addLeadingZeros('7.8.1'))
console.log(addLeadingZeros('7.08.1'))
console.log(addLeadingZeros('07.8.1'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this regex `/^\d\.|(?<=\.)\d\./g` it will select the first number and the number after the first dot, so it will only select date and month on your format.

You can use this like the code bellow

```
let regex = /^\d\.|(?<=\.)\d\./g;
console.log("8.8.2014".replace(regex, 
str => `0${str}`));
console.log("25.06.2014".replace(regex, 
str => `0${str}`));
console.log("9.06.2014".replace(regex, 
str => `0${str}`));
console.log("08.7.2014".replace(regex, 
str => `0${str}`));
console.log("1.1.1998".replace(regex, 
str => `0${str}`));
```

Now I'm gonna explain it part by part

## regex

The regex is broken by a `|` which tells it to either match expression before it or after it.

The first part is `^\d\.`, if you know the basics of regex, you'll know that it means see if there is a number right after which there is a dot at the beginning, it selects the date if there is only one digit representing it.

The second part is `(?<=\.)\d\.`, this part first sees if there is a dot before the string that is to be selected, then it sees if there is only one number after it then a dot. It will select the month if there is only one digit representing it.

Here the first part (?<=.) tells java script to seek for dot but not select it, if there is no dot before the number it won't select the string.

Now the last part g makes it select every instance of string which is matched.

So for the first example it selects the strings "8." and "8."

## .replace

`.replace` is a string function taking two argument, first the string/regex to match, in my code it is a regex.

Second is a string or a callback that returns a string, in my code it's a callback.

The callback can get the an argument which is the matched string.

Then I add the "0" before the matched string with a template string.

So the ending output is

```
08.08.2014
25.06.2014
09.06.2014
08.07.2014
01.01.1998
```

Hope my explanation helped.
I might be wrong at some places, as I'm still learning and use regex or even the callback of replace not very often.
Hope there weren't many mistakes.
If I'm wrong somewhere please let me know.